# sublime text 2 - how to switch from command mode MULTI CURSOR to insert mode

Tags: sublimetext2

I'm learning sublime keyboard commands (Vintage Mode / VintageEx), and find it useful to be able to select a column of text (in vim I just do Ctrl + v then up or down, depending on the direction of the column I want to select).  I guess sublime would handle this with multi cursor.  So what I do now (since I can't seem to figure out a normal column selection on Ubuntu 12.04) is this:

In command mode:

- shift v to select the starting line
- up or down to select lines above or below the selected line
- ctrl + shift + l to insert multiple cursors at the end of the selected lines (STILL IN COMMAND MODE)
- Now I want to be able to go into insert mode, but pressing "i" doesn't go to insert mode.  If I press "d" it will delete the selected lines and put me in insert mode...but I don't want to have to delete everything just to go into insert.

So, is there a good way to go into insert mode when you have multiple cursors in command mode?  Thanks so much for any advice!

Comment: you might find this link very handy https://gist.github.com/1207002

Comment: also this one http://www.kingluddite.com/tools/screencast-how-to-use-multi-cursors-with-sublime-text-2

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Multiple selections and cursors using vim / vintage mode and visual select in sublime text 2

In command mode:

- enter visual mode (v/V)
- select lines (j/k/movement)
- split into lines (Ctrl+Shift+L)
- exit visual mode (v)
- you should now be in command mode with multiple cursors :)
- enter input mode (i/a/etc..)
- edit with multiple cursors

Now how do you do it using vim's search keys, I can't get it yet. (/,n,N)

How many times did *you* try to enter command mode while writing your question ?

Comment: Can this also be done when searching for a string? If I type '/', then begin looking for a string and use CTRL+CMD+G (using a mac, dunno windows/linux), I get into visual mode and multi-select. But I can't split the lines and exit visual mode with multi-select.

Comment: @canistr if you are using MacOSX then the shortcut is Cmd+Shift+L.

Comment: Thank you for the full explanation. This is such a powerful way of working!